# Unit tests for performance regression in R

Tags: r, unit-testing, package

I’m doing some work in R with a shiny dashboard, and an R package which does the analysis which powers it.

On top of the unit tests to ensure functions behave as expected I use a lintr unit test to check for regressions in code style.

But I wondered if there was a way to test against regressions of performance (ie if adding or changing code has significantly impacted performance).

Clearly the underlying hardware plays a massive part - so you wouldn’t expect accurate timings - just an indicator of whether something is likely to be getting faster or slower.

Any ideas if such a package exists?

Comment: Why do you need a special package? I'd just run `system.time` inside a normal unit test and check if the timing is below a value beyond which I would deem the timing unacceptable. More is hardly possible because execution time depends on hardware, OS and system workload.

Comment: That works but doesn’t allow you to see the variability in your code. If your code uses an SQL query or large file access you may just observe the noise from that rather than see whether your code is getting generally quicker or generally slower.